# PHP Explode Numbers In Square Brackets

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have the following list which I get from Android into PHP in this format:

```
//How I get phonenumberlist 
$phonenumberlist = isset($_POST['PhoneNumberList']) ? $_POST['PhoneNumberList'] : '';
//The output of phonenumberlist when I print to text
$phonenumberlist = [0761234567, 072999999, 0731111111];
```

I would like to explode these numbers individually, I tried:

```
 $phonenumberlist_exploded = explode(',', $phonenumberlist);
 foreach ($phonenumberlist_exploded as $number)
 {
     echo $number;
 }
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
```

Comment: you may issues with the preceding zeros if you are displaying as number instead of text in above example consider wrapping in single quotes $phonenumberlist = ['0761234567', '072999999', '0731111111'];  or adding padding (if you know how many digits it will be)

Comment: If that is example data, did you mean `$phonenumberlist = '[0761234567, 072999999, 0731111111]';`

Comment: I added the items from android as string items and took the entire list as string and passed it to PHP which recognizes the list as int, also to answer your question, I have [int, int, int] without the string quote

Comment: var_dump($phonenumberlist);   what do you see? array I am betting.

Comment: `foreach ($phonenumberlist as $number) { echo $number; }` doesn't do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

`$phonenumberlist` is already an array. There's no need to explode it. Just iterate through it to echo out the values.

[You will have an issue with the leading zeros](https://eval.in/627165), however:

> Parse error: Invalid numeric literal

So you will need to wrap those values in quotes to make PHP handle them as strings:

```
$phonenumberlist = ['0761234567', '072999999', '0731111111'];
foreach($phonenumberlist as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/627167)

Comment: I have hundreds of phone numbers that I am getting, I only used 3 as an example, I do not want to manually add quotes as the list I am getting may change so is there a way to add the quotes systematically?

Answer (score 1):

You may convert the list like this:-

```
$phonenumberlist = '[0761234567, 072999999, 0731111111]';
$phonenumberlist = str_replace([' ', '[', ']', ','], ['', '["', '"]', '","'], $phonenumberlist);
$phonenumberlist = json_decode($phonenumberlist, true);
```

It will:-

1. Remove all spaces
2. Wrap all numbers with double quote (convert them to string type)
3. Convert the string to array using json_decode.

[Edit 1]
Another option:-

```
$phonenumberlist = '[0761234567, 072999999, 0731111111]';
$phonenumberlist = trim(trim($phonenumberlist, '['), ']');
$phonenumberlist = explode(', ', $phonenumberlist);
```

1. Trim the brackets
2. Explode the string to an array

Hope this helps.